# why does my program skip the if statement

Tags: java, logic, tcpserver

I have this tcp/ip program, where if the user enter's "Bye." it would stop the connection, and end the program. However, when I type Bye. from the client side, it won't do the if statement, but rather the other.

part of the program

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    { 
     System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine); 
     out.println(inputLine); 

     String csvline = getCsvLineVal (getLocation34CSV(getTag34Value(Tag34Location(getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getValueCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getVal34(input1,  input2)), getCSVLine( input3,  input4) );
     compareClientFixCSV( getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getValueCSV(parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getCSVTag(csvline), getCSVValue(csvline));

     if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) {
         System.out.println("Exit program"); 
         break;
         } 

     out.close(); 
     in.close(); 
     clientSocket.close(); 
     serverSocket.close();
    }
```

larger part of the program

```
public static void server(Scanner input1, Scanner input2, Scanner input3, Scanner input4) throws IOException{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 
    try { 
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(57634); 
        } 
    catch (IOException e) 
        { 
         System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 57635."); 
         System.exit(1); 
        } 

    Socket clientSocket = null; 
    System.out.println ("Waiting for connection.....");

    try { 
         clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
        } 
    catch (IOException e) 
        { 
         System.err.println("Accept failed."); 
         System.exit(1); 
        } 

    System.out.println ("Connection successful");
    System.out.println ("Waiting for input.....");

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), 
                                      true); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( 
            new InputStreamReader( clientSocket.getInputStream())); 

    String inputLine; 

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
         System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine); 
         out.println(inputLine); 

         String csvline = getCsvLineVal (getLocation34CSV(getTag34Value(Tag34Location(getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getValueCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getVal34(input1,  input2)), getCSVLine( input3,  input4) );
         compareClientFixCSV( getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getValueCSV(parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getCSVTag(csvline), getCSVValue(csvline));

         if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) {
             System.out.println("Exit program"); 
             break;
             } 

         out.close(); 
         in.close(); 
         clientSocket.close(); 
         serverSocket.close();
        }

}
```

Comment: Try `inputLine.trim().equals("Bye.");` and see if that still persists.

Answer (score 3):

From your code, if the user types "Bye." it will break the while loop but never close the input/output streams, nor the client/server sockets.

```
out.close(); 
in.close(); 
clientSocket.close(); 
serverSocket.close();
```

The code above happens in your `while` loop after your `if` statement. But if your `if` statement is true, the loop breaks and those statements are not reached.

Answer (score 1):

The break in your while loop is exiting your loop. It should look like this, otherwise your close will not get cleaned up.

```
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
         System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine); 
         out.println(inputLine); 

         String csvline = getCsvLineVal (getLocation34CSV(getTag34Value(Tag34Location(getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getValueCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getVal34(input1,  input2)), getCSVLine( input3,  input4) );
         compareClientFixCSV( getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getValueCSV(parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getCSVTag(csvline), getCSVValue(csvline));

         if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) {
             System.out.println("Exit program"); 
             break;
             } 
        }

         out.close(); 
         in.close(); 
         clientSocket.close(); 
         serverSocket.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple clients at the same time, you may want to handle each client in a new thread.